# How do I create redirect using host file

Tags: localhost

I am creating a .net MVC web app. I am trying to create a custom URL and redirect the user on the local host.

In my host file, I have added this

```
127.0.0.1    www.moss.namaz.no
127.0.0.1    api.moss.namaz.no
127.0.0.1    files.moss.namaz.no
```

My app listens to port 80. So when I type localhost in my browser, it takes me to my app but when I type www.moss.namaz.No, it says bad request. Do I have to add something else for it to work?

I also have this in my Route Config file

```
#if DEBUG
        // redirect localhost
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "LocalhostRedirect",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", path = "http://www.moss.namaz.no" },
            constraints: new
            {
                subdomain = new SubdomainRouteConstraint("localhost")
            }
        );
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use some proxy server like NginX to distribute requests. you can simply set the routing in Nginx like

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name www.moss.namaz.no;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name api.moss.namaz.no;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
}

//same for files.moss.namaz.no
```

In this way, all the domains are mapped to your ip, you can use either domain name to requests them.

P.s. the only problem is you need to set your app to listen to some other port, in my example, I have set 8080, because Nginx will listen to that port, you can also set Nginx to some other port as an alternative.